# How to add time delay in asynchronous coroutines?

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio, binance

I am attempting to retrieve historical data concurrently from Binance for each crypto pair in my database. I am running into bans with APIErrors, stating "APIError(code=-1003): Way too much request weight used; IP banned until 1629399758399. Please use the websocket for live updates to avoid bans."

How can I add a time delay to prevent reaching the API request weight limit which is 1200 per 1 Minute?

here's what I have as of now

```
import numpy as np
import json
import requests
import datetime, time
import aiohttp, asyncpg, asyncio
from asyncio import gather, create_task
from binance.client import AsyncClient
from multiprocessing import Process
import time
import config


async def main():
    # create database connection pool
    pool = await asyncpg.create_pool(user=config.DB_USER, password=config.DB_PASS, database=config.DB_NAME, host=config.DB_HOST, command_timeout=60)
    
    # get a connection
    async with pool.acquire() as connection:
        cryptos = await connection.fetch("SELECT * FROM crypto")

        symbols = {}
        for crypto in cryptos:
            symbols[crypto['id']] = crypto['symbol']

    await get_prices(pool, symbols)

async def get_prices(pool, symbols):
    try:
        # schedule requests to run concurrently for all symbols
        tasks = [create_task(get_price(pool, crypto_id, symbols[crypto_id])) for crypto_id in symbols]
        await gather(*tasks)           
        print("Finalized all. Retrieved price data of {} outputs.".format(len(tasks)))
        
    except Exception as e:
        print("Unable to fetch crypto prices due to {}.".format(e.__class__))
        print(e) 

async def get_price(pool, crypto_id, url): 
    try:
        candlesticks = []
        client = await AsyncClient.create(config.BINANCE_API_KEY, config.BINANCE_SECRET_KEY)
        
        async for kline in await client.get_historical_klines_generator(f"{crypto_id}".format(), AsyncClient.KLINE_INTERVAL_1HOUR, "18 Aug, 2021", "19 Aug, 2021"):
            candlesticks.append(kline)
        df = pd.DataFrame(candlesticks, columns = ["date","open","high","low","close","volume","Close time","Quote Asset Volume","Number of Trades","Taker buy base asset volume","Taker buy quote asset volume","Ignore"])
        df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[:, "date"], unit ='ms')
        df.drop(columns=['Close time','Ignore', 'Quote Asset Volume', 'Number of Trades', 'Taker buy base asset volume', 'Taker buy quote asset volume'], inplace=True)
        df.loc[:, "id"] = crypto_id
        df
        print(df)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Unable to get {} prices due to {}.".format(url, e.__class__))
        print(e)  

start = time.time()
if __name__ == "__main__":

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())

end = time.time()

print("Took {} seconds.".format(end - start))
```

Comment: If there are many `symbols`, you're probably running into all of those calls being called simultaneously. Maybe run them in smaller batches?

Comment: yes I agree I currently have about 1500 symbols in my database. I am still a noob to the programming world, could you explain how to run in smaller batches?

Comment: Well, think about how you might slice `symbols` into smaller batches and loop over them as you currently do with the full `symbols` list?

Answer (score 3):

You can create an instance of a custom class that will keep the count of currently active requests (and timing of requests) - and only allow one request to proceed if that guard says it is ok.

Python´s `async with` command would be nice to use in such a construct since it can both guard a block, and decrease the active request count with minimal intervention in the code you already have.

This can proceed like this- the line in your code that actually trigger the requests is:

`client = await AsyncClient.create(config.BINANCE_API_KEY, config.BINANCE_SECRET_KEY)`

So, if we can ensure this line is called at most 1200 times per minute, having to yield to the mainloop while it does not happen, we are good.
While it would be possible to burst 1200 (-1) calls and them waiut one minute, the code will be both easier to write, and the API limit will be more  respected in its spirit, if we simply yield one call each (60s / 1200) ( x 90% for a 10% nice margin) seconds.

The `async with` will call the class' `__aenter__` method. In there we can simply check the time interval since the last API call and sleep until this time has passed.
(Actually, we will need one instance of the class per task, as `__aenter__` needs to be called in each instance). But in order not to depend on a global "counter", we can create a factory function that will create a guard per API that needs limiting - and we keep that one in a global variable)

So, you can add this factory function to your program, and then create a guard-class on your main function and use "async with" inside the tasks code:

```
def create_rate_limit_guard(rate_limit=1200, safety_margin=0.9):
    """Rate limit is given in maximum requests per minute.
    """
    
    # TBD: it would easy to have code to throttle by maximum active requests
    # instead of total requests per minute. 
    # I will just let the accounting of concurrent_requests in place, though
    
    class Guard:
        request_interval = (60 / rate_limit) * safety_margin
        current_requests = 0
        max_concurrent_requests = 0
        last_request = 0
        
        async def __aenter__(self):
            cls = self.__class__
            cls.current_requests += 1
            if (throttle_wait:= time.time() - last_request) < cls.request_interval:
                await asyncio.sleep(throttle_wait)
            cls.current_requests += 1
            cls.last_request = time.time()
        
        async def __aexit__(self, exc_type, exc, tb):
            cls = self.__class__
            cls.max_concurrent_requests = max(cls.max_concurrent_requests, cls.current_requests)
            cls.current_requests -= 1
        
    return Guard
```

And in your code, you could just change get_price to this, and create the guard class (last line before `if ...__main__`:

```
async def get_price(pool, crypto_id, url): 
    try:
        candlesticks = []
        # consider having a single client application wise - you are creating one per task. 
        with BinanceLimitGuard():
            client = await AsyncClient.create(config.BINANCE_API_KEY, config.BINANCE_SECRET_KEY)
        
        
        # as the actual calls to the remote endpoint are done inside the client code itself,
        # we can't just run "async for" on the generator - instead we have to throttle
        # all the "for" interactions. So we "unfold" the async for in a while/anext 
        # structure so that we can place the guard before each interation:
        klines_generator = await client.get_historical_klines_generator(
            f"{crypto_id}".format(), AsyncClient.KLINE_INTERVAL_1HOUR, "18 Aug, 2021", "19 Aug, 2021")
        while True:
            try:
                with BinanceLimitGuard():
                    kline = await klines_generator.__anext__()
            except StopAsyncIteration:
                break
        
            candlesticks.append(kline)
        
        df = pd.DataFrame(candlesticks, columns = ["date","open","high","low","close","volume","Close time","Quote Asset Volume","Number of Trades","Taker buy base asset volume","Taker buy quote asset volume","Ignore"])
        df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[:, "date"], unit ='ms')
        df.drop(columns=['Close time','Ignore', 'Quote Asset Volume', 'Number of Trades', 'Taker buy base asset volume', 'Taker buy quote asset volume'], inplace=True)
        df.loc[:, "id"] = crypto_id
        print(df)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Unable to get {} prices due to {}.".format(url, e.__class__))
        print(e)  

BinanceLimitGuard = create_rate_limit_guard(300)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # all code that is meant to take place when your file is run as a program
    # should be guarded in this if block. Importing your file should not "print"
    start = time.time()
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())

     end = time.time()

     print("Took {} seconds.".format(end - start))
```

Note that while I designed the guard to "1200 requests per minute" - I sugested a limit of "300" parallel tasks per minute above, in `BinanceLimitGuard = create_rate_limit_guard(300)` - because, checking the source code for the binance client itself, it does perform several requests of itself in a call to "get_historical_klines" - and that code has embedded a limit of 3 calls per second - but which take place  per generator, so we can't account for them on the outside code.

If this still not work, it can be made to work by subclassing (or monkeypatching) the AsyncClient itself and placing the limit  rate on its internal `_request_api` internal method, at this place https://github.com/sammchardy/python-binance/blob/a6f3048527f0f2fd9bc6591ac1fdd926b2a29f3e/binance/client.py#L330  - then you can go back to the "1200 limit" as it will account all internal calls. (drop a comment if you need to resort to this, I could complete this answer or add another one)

Comment: I definitely needed time to digest that! So grateful for your help and expertise. I would love to be able to resort to this!

Comment: The initial recipe ends up being quite useful for generic projects. Just after I wrote it I saw it would no apply cleanly to the binance api (so the considerations and code-unfolding in the last part)